# Why doesn't Java allow "new List<T>"?

Tags: java, generics

To create a List, why doesn't Java allow them to be created then elements added one by one?

**This works:**

```
public static List<TrackedItem> create(List<Item> items)
{
    TrackedItem[] arr = new TrackedItem[items.size()];

    int i = 0;
    for (Item item : items)
    {
        arr[i] = TrackedItem.createOrUpdate(item);

        i++;
    }

    return java.util.Arrays.asList(arr);
}
```

**This does not work** (`tracked.add()` causes a `NullPointerException`):

```
public static List<TrackedItem> create(List<Item> items)
{
    List<TrackedItem> tracked = java.util.Collections.emptyList();

    for (Item item : items)
    {
        tracked.add(TrackedItem.createOrUpdate(item));
    }

    return tracked;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your code throws a NPE? Because it should throw a `UnsupportedOperationException` because the return value of `emptyList()` can't be modified (by design).

Comment: It throws a `NullPointerException`? Really? It should thrown an `UnsupportedOperationException`: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E)

Comment: The answers below are correct, but I tried code similar to the yours and I get UnsupportedOperationException on a call to add() because List is not a concrete type. I'm not sure how you even getting this to get to a point where a NullPointerException can be thrown - there might be something going on in createOrUpdate()...

Comment: but where is the `“new List<T>”` from the title?. And is this question really related to `generics`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

java.util.Collections.emptyList();

> static
>    List
>    emptyList()
>             Returns the empty list (immutable).

That means, you will not be able to change this list.

Its defined:

> static List  EMPTY_LIST
>             The empty list (immutable).

Quotes from [Java sun reference](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)

Edit:

To create a new list you could use e.g.

```
List myList = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
```

Comment: +1: The problem here is in attempting to modify the value returned from `Collections.emptyList()`, nothing to do with generic parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following syntax:

```
public static List<TrackedItem> create(List<Item> items)
{
    List<TrackedItem> tracked = new ArrayList<TrackedItem>();

    for (Item item : items)
    {
        tracked.add(TrackedItem.createOrUpdate(item));
    }

    return tracked;
}
```

Comment: NB You need to instantiate a list of a specific type (in this case ArrayList, could also have been LinkedList, etc.) to which you can add your items.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a misunderstanding.

Even if it is called `emptyList`, it isn't a list which is just empty and ready to be populated. This `emptyList` is designed to be empty at all times. You can't add to this special list.

To get a 'usable' empty list you can either

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();  // create a new one or
list.add("if you have an list");
list.clear();                                 // just clear it
```

Answer (score 1):

create a new arrayList by :

```
List<T> tracked = new ArrayList<T>();
```

List is only an interface ... you can't make a new one. you only can implement it.